# how to change ipmi user with one command

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool, openbmc

i want to change existing user password. i ran this command
ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.1.1 -U USER -P 'PASSWORD' user set password 10 "&UJM2wsx"

i got an error
IPMI command failed: Request data field length limit exceeded
Set User Password command failed (user 10)

when i ran same command without password at the end i was prompted to insert password twice and it worked.
is there a way to echo password twice to ipmitool user set password command?

p.s i tried to delete the user and re create it but there is not delete option from cli only from web gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't require to echo the password twice, both must work. Not sure, why you are getting data field length exceed error.

try it with
ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.1.1 -U USER -P 'PASSWORD' user set password 10 "&UJM2wsx" -v

also with
ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.1.1 -U USER -P 'PASSWORD' user set password 10 "&UJM2wsx" -vv

Also, make sure user 10 is having a proper user name first, with "ipmitool user list" command.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue when trying to update the password of user 2 (ADMIN) on one of my servers using ipmitool.

I was trying to set the password using the following command;
`ipmitool user set password 2 ADMIN`

This failed with the following error:
`IPMI command failed: Request data field length limit exceeded Set User Password command failed (user 2)`

The way to fix this is actually quite simple. Since some time, Supermicro actually does not allow certain passwords for BMC users unless they have the following requirements:
use lowercase, capital, numbers and special characters.

So, to set my password I included this using e.g. `Admin123!` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Ah, that's what it means, thanks.  Fwiw, I didn't need the !

Answer (score 2):

This below is incomplete:

*"The way to fix this is actually quite simple. Since some time, Supermicro actually does not allow certain passwords for BMC users unless they have the following requirements: use lowercase, capital, numbers and special characters."*

How to put your own (and maybe insecure) password:

1. You need to login in the ipmi webpage with the current password.
2. Go to 'Configuration>Users>'
3. Click on the 'here' link:

   "For more advanced user settings, please click. **here**"
4. Then lower the password security requirements.

That's all.

Comment: This is really helped.